# How to do responsive design in bootstrap 2.3.2

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have to use bootstrap v 2.3 instead of v3.But there is an allignment issue.The link for fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Ljfr1wgc/2/

Here i want to allign the 4 text boxes (each of different size) in one row.I tried using different values of span,but for my desktop it works but for mobile and large devices its not working (i want all textboxes of medium size in mobile device alligned vertically).Where am i going wrong ?

```
<div class="container main-container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8">
        <form role="form">
            <div id="placeholder1">
                <div id="template">
                    <div class="fieldsetBorder">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="span1">
                                <label class="label-Style ">Mini </label>
                                <input type="text" class="label-class " value="Mini size needed">
                            </div>
                            <div class="span1">
                                <label class="label-Style">Small</label>
                                <input type="text" class="label-text " placeholder="Small size needed">
                            </div>
                            <div class="span1">
                                <label class="label-Style">Large</label>
                                <input type="text" class="label-text" placeholder="Large size needed">
                            </div>
                            <div class="span1">
                                <label class="label-Style">Medium</label>
                                <input type="text" class="label-text " placeholder="Medium size needed">
                            </div>                                  
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="span2">
                                <label class="label-Style">Medium</label>
                                <input type="text" class="label-text input-mini" placeholder="Medium size needed">
                            </div>
                            <div class="span2">
                                <label class="label-Style">Medium</label>
                                <input type="text" class="label-text input-mini" placeholder="Medium size needed">
                            </div>
                            <div class="span2">
                                <label class="label-Style">Medium</label>
                                <input type="text" class="label-text input-mini" placeholder="Medium size needed">
                            </div>
                            <div class="span2">
                                <label class="label-Style">Medium</label>
                                <input type="text" class="label-text input-mini" placeholder="Medium size needed">
                            </div>                          
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="span8">
                                <label class="label-Style" >Description</label>
                                <textarea rows="3" placeholder="Enter Description"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-square" onclick="Add()"></i><span>Add attachment</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean this? https://jsfiddle.net/Ljfr1wgc/4/

Comment: @joci93 yes that only ...